# Book about Wife POV killing her husband and throwing his body down a well

Tags: identification-request

I read a book a while back where a woman narrates the story of her marriage and how her husband ends up dead and she throws his body in a well (plot line not dissimilar to Stephen King's 1922), but I simply cannot remember the title or the author. It's not a long book. The wife had worked as a maid for an old woman who planted the seed about offing her husband. The wife narrates the story in her very distinctive manner, very peculiar accent.

Answer (score 4):

Stephen King's **Dolores Claiborne**, perhaps?

The book is narrated by the titular character, although I don't recall whether her manner is distinctive or her accent peculiar.
Here are the plot similarities to what you remember (with some necessary plot spoilers):

> Over the course of the book, Dolores reveals she **murdered her husband by throwing him down a well.**
>  The **seed for this was planted by the old woman for who she worked as a maid.**

The similarities are considerable.

According to [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolores_Claiborne) it is 305 pages long, so it is **not a long book.**

If this is the book you're remembering, it's funny that you note the similarities to another Stephen King work.

Comment: Her manner is most definitely distinctive and her accent is a Down East Maine accent—maybe not that peculiar if you live in Maine, but certainly not standard American.